# react native, react-navigation, TabNavigator, judge something when executing go back by clicking the button in the left top corner

Tags: react-native

`react-navigation`

Github:

https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation

I use `react-navigation`, in this case, I click the navigation Back button, the App will show father view.

My need is a condition is true, I click the go back button in the left top corner, it executes. If the condition is false, I show an alert only.

I am using the redux.
In other words, how to listen the `go back` redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For navigate by condition, you can configure back button in `YourComponent.nativationOptions`, e.g.:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  static nativationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    headerLeft:
        <Button title='Back' onPress={() => {
          if (condition) {
            navigation.goBack()
          } else {
            // Do alert
          }
        }} />
  })
}
```

If your condition depends `props`, you can get it by `navigation.state.params`.

If your condition depends an internal state of your component, call `navigation.setParams` to put a condition callback in your component, or you can put the condition value when condition changed.

To integrate with redux, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux.

Comment: Is  `static nativationOptions`  `react-navigation`'s API?  Have you created a user-defined backButton?

Comment: See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-options about `navigationOptions`, when you custom `backLeft`, `react-navigation` will render it, or else it provides HeaderBackButton (see https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/src/views/HeaderBackButton.js). So in the code above, you need a button component, or you can use `HeaderBackButton` of `react-navigation` by `import { HeaderBackButton } from 'react-navigation'`